# Don't duck audio for system sound

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to play a "ding" sound over an audio track.

When setting up the player, we have:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                .setCategory(.playback,
                             mode: .default,
                             policy: .longFormAudio,
                             options: [])

try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

Then later on, a user action (e.g. tapping) does:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1407))
```

This works well. The only issue is that the playing track gets ducked to play the system sound.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Strangely, in XCode simulator, the tracks play in parallel and no ducking occurs.

Update: updating to this has no effect:

```
 try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                .setCategory(.playback,
                             mode: .default,
                             policy: .longFormAudio,
                             options: .mixWithOthers)
```

Comment: You need to set the `mixWithOthers` option when you specify the [`.playback`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/category/1616509-playback) category if you don't want ducking.

Comment: I have updated the question, but adding `mixWithOthers` seems to have no effect. I'm running on from Xcode on real device, and the ducking still occurs :(

Answer (score 0):

try

```
do{
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient)
   try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
} catch {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```